# Функция перегрузки ПК, стала работать с переменным успехом

Tags: delphi, windows-10

На протяжении полугода пользовался функцией для перегрузки ПК, проблем не возникало.
Но вот уже около недели, программа с этой функцией выдает фиртеля.  Т.е. есть случаи, когда программе удается перегрузить ПК, а бывают случаи, когда с системы выгружаются программы, а перезагрузки ПК нет.
До этого не доставлял никаких программ.

Функция:

```
function TFMain.MyExitWindows(RebootParam: Longword): Boolean;
var  
  TTokenHd: THandle;  
  TTokenPvg: TTokenPrivileges;  
  cbtpPrevious: DWORD;
  rTTokenPvg: TTokenPrivileges;
  pcbtpPreviousRequired: DWORD;  
  tpResult: Boolean;  
const  
  SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = 'SeShutdownPrivilege';  
begin  
  if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then  
  begin  
    tpResult := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY,  
      TTokenHd);  
    if tpResult then  
    begin  
      tpResult := LookupPrivilegeValue(nil,  
                                       SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME,  
                                       TTokenPvg.Privileges[0].Luid);  
      TTokenPvg.PrivilegeCount := 1;  
      TTokenPvg.Privileges[0].Attributes := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;  
      cbtpPrevious := SizeOf(rTTokenPvg);  
      pcbtpPreviousRequired := 0;  
      if tpResult then  
        Windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(TTokenHd,  
                                      False,
                                      TTokenPvg,  
                                      cbtpPrevious, 
                                      rTTokenPvg, 
                                      pcbtpPreviousRequired); 
    end;
  end;
  Result := ExitWindowsEx(RebootParam, 0);
end;
```

Ее вызов:

```
MyExitWindows(EWX_REBOOT or EWX_FORCE);
```

В чем может быть закавыка?

P.S.:
- ОС: Windows10;
- Delphi 10.2

Comment: А почему не использовали вызов из Вашего кода стандартной команды, которая работает гарантированно: shutdown /r /f /t 0

Comment: `AdjustTokenPrivileges` может не дает вам прав на ребут. проверьте что возвращается

Comment: @Justicet - поставил "*shutdown /r /f /t 0*". Только мне кажется, что параметр "/f" лишний, у меня же "/t" = 0... Если пользоваться http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/shutdown.html

Comment: @teran 29 , К сожалению, результат функции "*AdjustTokenPrivileges*" не удастся проверить, т.к. (проверку) программу нужно запускать, на том ПК, на котором происходит сам процесс работы программы. А на том ПК, на котором идет разработка, эта функция выдает "**True**" Но я обязательно это проверю, Это наверно результат придется в лог писать, т.к. сама программа выгружается из памяти?

Comment: @Konstantin78 : параметр /f даёт возможность экстренно, но правильно закрыть приложения, /t 0 - просто выключение через 0 сек с разрывом соединений